# How to localize BottomNavigationBarItem labels

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

Is there any workaround to translate the BottomNavigationBarItem into different languages?
I use Lang.getString(context, key) to access a map(loaded from a json file) to fetch the right translation, it doesn't make any sense to hard code the label like this, label: "Home". what should I do?

```
PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: _pageSwipped,
        children: <Widget>[Page1()],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            label: Lang.getString(context, key), // it doesn't work because it should be constant.
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currenIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        iconSize: _deviceSize.size.height * 0.046,
        selectedFontSize: _deviceSize.size.height * 0.023,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        onTap: _bottomTapped,
      )
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove **const** keyword from line

```
 items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
 ......
 ......
 ]
```

Comment: This seems to solve the error. Any explanation behind this?

Comment: every line with "context" can't be const because it means it can be changed on the fly by change for example, system language like here